# Get values in one column that correspond with max value of other columns in a matrix (R)?

Tags: r

OK this is my first stack overflow question..so please feel free to critique.
Here goes:
I have a matrix (more specifically, time series) with time in column 1 and the values of individual observations in the subsequent columns (X1,X2,..X10) like so:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:30,30), ncol=6))
time<-seq(0,9,1)
df.ts<-cbind(time,df)
```

What I am trying to extract are values in the 'time' column which corresponds to maximum values
in each of X variables?
I could extract the max values from each column like so:

```
max_vals<-apply(df,2,max)
```

As a first step I tried to get the individual indices using:

```
  ind=rep(NA,10)
    for( i in 1:length(max_vals)) { 
    if (df.ts[,i]==max_vals[i])
    ind<-df.ts$time[i]
    }
```

This does not work with following errors:

```
1: In if (df.ts[, i] == max_vals[i]) ind <- df.ts$time[i] :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (df.ts[, i] == max_vals[i]) ind <- df.ts$time[i] :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (df.ts[, i] == max_vals[i]) ind <- df.ts$time[i] :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In if (df.ts[, i] == max_vals[i]) ind <- df.ts$time[i] :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
5: In if (df.ts[, i] == max_vals[i]) ind <- df.ts$time[i] :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
6: In if (df.ts[, i] == max_vals[i]) ind <- df.ts$time[i] :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Also even if I am able to get the indices out it is more useful if I could get the df.ts$time values that correspond to the max values in each of the other columns.

Any leads will be greatly appreciated.Thanks  for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code isn't working because `if` requires a single Boolean, and the left side of your Boolean statement has length > 1, resulting in a Boolean vector with length > 1.  You could do something with `ifelse`, which will take length > 1 inputs, but in this case `which.max` is much simpler.

```
df <- data.frame(time=seq(0,9,1), matrix(sample(1:30,30), ncol=6))
df$time[apply(df,2,which.max)]
```

This will take only the first occurrence of the maximum value, so if there are multiple time points that have the max, you might want to do something else. In your sample data, the first five rows are always the same as the last five rows, so you always have two occurrences.  More generally, though, there won't always be the same number, so you'll need a list to store these results, so you could `lapply` to loop over the columns of the data frame and `which` to find all the indices that correspond to the max.

```
lapply(df, function(x) df$time[which(x==max(x))])
```

Comment: +1, but do you want `df$time` instead of `df.ts$time`?

Comment: Very nicely done and explained..yes it will be df$time.

Comment: Thanks, and typo fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `which`:

```
max.ind <- lapply(df.ts[,-1], function(x) which(x==max(x)))
lapply(max.ind, function(i, DF) DF[i,1], DF=df.ts)
# $X1
# [1] 4 9
# 
# $X2
# [1] 0 5
# 
# $X3
# [1] 2 7
# 
# $X4
# [1] 0 5
# 
# $X5
# [1] 0 5
# 
# $X6
# [1] 2 7
```